# Is there any way to rotate a magic trackpad?

Tags: macos, trackpad, magic-trackpad

I want to use my magic trackpad while it's rotated, as if in 'portrait' mode.

I can't find any option to make it work like this, unlike a display `Rotation` option.

Is there a way for me to use it this way? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three options that I'm aware of, but depending on the version of macOS you're running, probably only one of them is a real chance of doing exactly what you want.

In summary:

- Use Terminal commands to rotate the trackpad orientation. However, the commands I'm aware of only work to rotate it 180° instead of 90°. It also doesn't work for macOS Sierra or macOS High Sierra. If you're running an earlier version of macOS and rotating 180° is an option for you, then see details below for Terminal commands.
- Try using [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com), however this is now on its last legs as an option. It's worked brilliantly for many users for a long time, but for various reasons is no longer maintained
- Try using [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net). This is probably your best bet. You can install it for free for 45 days to test how well it meets your needs.

**Terminal commands**

If you decide that rotating your trackpad 180° will meet your needs, and assuming you're running an older version of macOS, then follow these steps:

1. Launch Terminal (usually found in Applications > Utilities)
2. Enter the following command (or copy and paste it):

   `sudo sudo defaults write com.apple.MultitouchSupport ForceAutoOrientation YES`
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Enter the following command (or copy and paste it):

   `sudo defaults write com.apple.trackpad.orientation TrackpadOrientationMode 1`
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Once you've entered both commands you should be able to just turn Bluetooth off and then on again to activate the change in orientation.

Comment: Thanks, but not able to rotate 90°.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "older version of macOS"?

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert Apologies for the delay in responding, I'm only now catching up with my inbox. In the context of this answer I meant a version of macOS older than macOS Sierra (10.12). I don't recall if it works on El Capitan (10.11), but certainly on older versions.

Comment: I see. Yeah, very sad, they removed it. Guess the rotation trick won't work with the new trackpad, so they don't need that feature anymore... I checked BetterTouchTool, but that doesn't do it either. I also started digging into programming a fix myself, but the mouse pointer seems to bee implemented far deeper than the go-to CGEvent. Need to dig a little deeper...

Comment: Oh and never mind! I know these moments and also don't always respond within minutes ;)

Comment: Has anyone figured this out for 10.14 Mojave or 10.15 Catalina?

Comment: @Alexander Call `MTDeviceSetSurfaceOrientation` private method (in private multitouch framework). Also you can't do 90 deg natively, but you can set up an event tap to capture mouse movement and use cgwarpmousecursorposition to adjust